# Physics that calls for deeply nested Lie/Poisson brackets

Tags: mathematical-physics, commutator, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets

I've been scouring physics for non-associative situations, particularly where study of [quasigroups and loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loops) might come in handy (they always seem to be left out).  The poisson and lie brackets form a Moufang loop, but I rarely see it more than one deep where the structure starts to show.  It's common to see $\{x, y\}$, but never exotic things like $\{\{x, y\}, \{z, \{w, q\}\}\}$.  There's always the cross product, but because it operates in 3 dimensions, its typically not value-added to have a long chain of cross products.

Are there situations in physics where one would see such deeply nested non-associative algebras?  I presume they would be identified as problem cases, as non-associativity is a bit of a pest.

Comment: Does $e^A B e^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots$ count?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  but this is the apotheosis of associativity. Isn't the author seeking non-associative examples? The ultimate associative multi-bracket is the celebrated Groenewold anomaly, $\{x^3 ,p^3\}+ \frac{1}{12} \{\{p^2,x^3\} , \{x^2,p^3\}\}  $,  when properly quantized.